# Why do the SVG properties of an SVG element sometimes show up as accessible and sometimes not?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

```
self.popover = self.canvas.append("svg:rect")
  .attr("id", popoverId)
  ...

self.popover.getBBox()
TypeError: Object [object SVGRectElement] has no method 'getBBox'
```

But if I pass another SVG element to a function as "this" when it is clicked on, I get access to all of the SVG methods.

Answer (score 4):

This d3 method does the trick:

```
self.popover.node().getBBox()
```

Comment: Correct. self.popover is a D3 selection, while self.popover.node() is an SVGRectElement.